# Attaching Java source for 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, attachment

I am using the Eclipse IDE and would like to debug.  When I try to step into the Java code, I get a message "Source not found".  With previous versions of Java like 1.5, I was able to download a src.zip file, go into the "Installed JREs" area, edit the rt.jar attribute then add the "Source Attachment". Then I am able to step into Java source. This works fine when I have the src.zip.

Is there a src.zip for Java 1.6?  Has anyone successfully attached 1.5 src.zip to a 1.6 jre in Eclipse?

Comment: It's the same for 1.6. You will get a `src.zip` with the JDK. Hope you're not looking into the JRE?

Answer (score 1):

Download the Java 6 JDK and install it.  Add it to installed JRE's.  Set it as default Java runtime.

When you debug now, you should have src.zip attached automatically.

(Note:  It works differently for recent Java releases on OS X)