# I can't use the debugger in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno. Whenever I try to use the debugger on any program, a new window appears in the editor pane titled `URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available` and a message in it saying `"Source not found"` in red. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Here's the picture

[image]

Comment: Read the Eclipse manual. You must attach the sources to see them.

Comment: I have the source code! Its my handwritten program which I am debugging!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching Java source for 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079633/attaching-java-source-for-1-6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because you (accidentally) created a breakpoint somewhere in `URLClassLoader`.

Check the "Breakpoints" view (it's next to the "Variables" view) in your debugger perspective. There should be a breakpoint which reads `URLClassLoader$1.run()` or at least `URLClassLoader`. Select and delete it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Actually, I had `NullPointerException` & "ClassLoaderException` in the breakpoint list (not `URLClassLoader`) & I deleted both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I also had that problem with Eclipse Juno, then I got back to Indigo and I strongly recommend you to get back to Indigo. Juno has some bugs and it consumes more memory than the previous releases (galileo, indigo, helios, etc). The user interface seems to be better, but I prefer the performance over the view. But it's only a recommendation I gave you since I had the same problem, I'm happy debugging with Indigo :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, Indigo's a lot better.